# Calculating number of points within different parts of raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I want to calculate the number of points that overlap a raster with different areas (the areas have different numerical values).

How can I determine how many points fall within each area of the raster?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

1. Convert the raster to polygons using [Raster To Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm)
2. [Dissolve](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) the polygons using gridcode field as `dissolve_field`
3. Follow ESRI's [How To: Count the number of point features within a polygon](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008599) which will tell you to:

> Create a count field and a spatial join between the point shapefile
>   and the polygon shapefile.

[image]

Comment: I have now created a polygon layer from the raster. Are you saying I have to calculate the number of points for each individual resulting polygon (after dividing the raster into polygons)? Is there no way to calculate the number of points based on the attributes of the polygons (they have different numerical values)?

Comment: Raster to polygons will generate only one polygon feature class. The polygons will get the raster values as attributes. You should only need to follow the steps one time.

Comment: I can't follow your explanation. I have tried several times. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [extract multivalue to point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-multi-values-to-points.htm) in order to get the value of the raster under each point. Then you open the attribute table of your point layer and you click on the raster_value column to summarize the number of points for each of the values.